# Can we able to install exe files on cloud space?

Tags: architecture, cloud, saas

Hi I would like to install a Dataloader software in cloud space , because I am using Ubuntu dataloader is exe file so i like install in the cloud

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about cloud but if you want to execute .exe file ( that is windows executable ) on ubuntu then you need wine ( for native win32 applications ) or mono (  for .net applications  ).  :)

Comment: Hi Tiger, Thanks for your suggestion. I would like to install it in cloud so it will used by different OS user